# How to get checkmarked items in TableView in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I want to get a check marked items in my `tableView` but I couldn't find any solution about this. I tried to use `NSArray` but it crash with `'Array out of bounds'` error it causes crash because when I want to remove at `indexPath` it doesn't have that index and it crash so I decided to use **unordered collection** like `Dictionary` but this time it doesn't remove items in selected `indexPath` exactly. There is my codes in my `TableView`.

```
let services = ["1", "2", "3"]
var selectedServices = [Int: String]()
var selectedServicesArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var saveButtonOutlet: UIButton!
// MARK: - LifeCycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DesignSettings().clipComponents([saveButtonOutlet])
}

// MARK: - TableView DataSource & Delegate Methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return services.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if selectedRow.accessoryType == .None {
            selectedRow.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            selectedServices[indexPath.row] = selectedRow.textLabel?.text
        } else {
            selectedRow.accessoryType = .None
            selectedServices.removeValueForKey(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
    for (_, value) in selectedServices {
        self.selectedServicesArray.append(value)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = services[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

And there is the `console` print;

```
["1", "1", "2"]
["3"]
["2", "3", "2"]
["2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2"]
```

How can i solve this problem ? 
What is the correct way to get check marked items in tableView? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 issues:

- You're constantly `append`-ing to the `selectedServicesArray` in your `for` loop. To fix this you'd have to remove all objects and then add all the selected.
- You're using an intermediate object to handle the selected values, I'd suggest adding / removing the items directly to the `selectedServicesArray` like this:

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      if let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
          if selectedRow.accessoryType == .None {
              selectedRow.accessoryType = .Checkmark
              selectedServicesArray.append((selectedRow.textLabel?.text)!)
          } else {
              selectedRow.accessoryType = .None

              let indexToDelete = selectedServicesArray.indexOf((selectedRow.textLabel?.text)!)
              selectedServicesArray.removeAtIndex(indexToDelete!)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: let indexToDelete = selectedServicesArray.indexOf((selectedRow.textLabel?.text)!)
            selectedServicesArray.removeAtIndex(indexToDelete!) is the trick Thank you. 

It works perfectly now. How can i put checkmark  selectedServices items in my tableView ?

Comment: No problem, but I didn't quite get your question, do you want to add a checkmark on the selected cells?

Comment: I will store this data to Parse and when I get this data from Parse sometime I want to show stored services(selectedServices) in my tableView with checkmarks.

Comment: Add this to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `if selectedServicesArray.contains((selectedRow.textLabel?.text)!)` `selectedRow.accessoryType = .Checkmark` `else` `selectedRow.accessoryType = .None`

Comment: It works thank you. When I want to checkmark another item in tableView and it removes other check marked items in my array and adds only new selected item. For Example: I check marked and added "1" and "2" to my selectedServicesArray it shows this items with checkmark. When I check marked "3" it shows 3 items with checkmated but it adds only last item to my selectedServicesArray it deletes last 2 items any solution ?

Comment: Ok I found the solution I added the append and removeAtIndex items in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method it works. Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Hi @Islam Q There is a another problem here in our code. I expanded my servicesArray.count for new items. In this time when I select the first row in my table it checkmarks random another items. When I decrease my servicesArray.count with deleting some items. It works like a charm. I think we have reusable cell problem ?

Comment: Yes, in your cellForRow... you should check whether that row should be selected or unselected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't understand why you need `selectedServicesArray` and what exactly is your problem. You should always show your 3 services? In your code you modified `selectedServices` and `selectedServicesArray`, but in `numberOfRowsInSection` always was `services.count` - 3. So it's strange. And you didn't update your tableView after changing checkmark. So I provided some code:

```
let services = ["1", "2", "3"]
var selectedServices = [Int: Bool]()

// MARK: - TableView DataSource & Delegate Methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return services.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if selectedRow.accessoryType == .None {
            selectedRow.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            selectedServices[indexPath.row] = true
        } else {
            selectedRow.accessoryType = .None
            selectedServices[indexPath.row] = false
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // check selectedServices[indexPath.row] and update your layout

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Parse.com is requires NSArray to store this datas so I added selectedServicesArray and want to append selectedServices to this array so I can store this array to Parse.com.